# How to get old version on TFS of c# project and make edits on it and check In the old version with edits?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, changeset

I'm working on WPF c# project , I need to get specific version and make edits on it then check in the whole old version with my edits .

what I'm do is that I'm get Specific Version from TFS then make my edit then when check in i found that latest files before check In come again on my check In version , I didn't need them I just need the full old version with my edits.Please Advise..

Comment: Have you considered a roll back to version? if you don't need the latest changes and want to change a previous version then rolling back is also an option

Comment: Rollback will delete my newer versions right ! but i need to keep newer versions on my history , I just need old version to be replaced temporary on my local directory in order  to make some edits then check in this old version again

Comment: Which version control are you using? Git or TFVC?

Comment: Microsoft team foundation server 2010 on Visual studio 2010

Comment: Therefore it's TFVC. By the way, those are both *really* old. I'd recommend you push to get those updated. If you fall behind on technology, it's hard to get caught back up and you miss out on a lot of great enhancements and bug fixes. 7 years worth in your case.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you edit your question to more precisely describe what you want to do and why you want to do it? It **sounds** like you're saying you want to modify an existing changeset.

Comment: yes , The client need specific version Fix on my project so I didn't need latest changes to come with this old version , I get specific version on TFS and make edits then check in after check in i found that checked in version contain latest versions changes I need only old version with my edits not need latest edits after this version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want to change the existing changeset, unfortunately you cannot do that.

If you want to get the old version sources, you can Rollback the changeset, you may need to resolve the conflicts during the rollback. ([Rollback Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

If you want to get back and edit the sources based on the old version, then you can create a new branch as Siraf mentioned (eg : **Branch from specific changeset**). Then you can track the later changes on this new branch ( edit and check in the changes into the new branch.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a branch! get specific version will not help.
You need to make a branch for the customer, then fix the issue in the customer branch and the main branch